# Python twilio send sms with hyperlink in body

Tags: python, twilio

The following script below works. How ever I cant find an example to create the "click here" a hyperlink to lets say [www.amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com) when someone touches it on there mobile device

```
import os
from twilio.rest import Client

# Your Account SID from twilio.com/console
account_sid = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
# Your Auth Token from twilio.com/console
auth_token  = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.messages.create(
    to="+19051234567", 
    from_="+19057654321",
    body="Summer Sale Click here 35% off")

print(message.sid)
```

"Click here" should be a link to amazon site.

Comment: I'm not sure if SMS has function for this. As for me programs in mobile devices recognizes urls in SMS and they convert them to clickable links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SMS does not support hyperlinked text. The best you can do is to send the URL as part of the body of the SMS message.

```py
message = client.messages.create(
    to="+19051234567", 
    from_="+19057654321",
    body="Summer Sale! For 35% off click here: https://example.org")
```

Comment: Thank you I was not aware of the fact! I don't see what you just stated anywhere I was looking for a feature that does not exists. Your answer saved me hours of googling.